# XML file inside of Properties file in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to read xml file in a properties file in java? for example i have `config.xml` inside `config.properties` and get the value of the data inside the `xml` file  like this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Config>
 <Name>Goku</Name>
</Config>
```

Comment: That's simply not a valid properties file. If you want XML, use an XML file...

Comment: Oh i see, I'm just confused.. btw thank you @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store xml as String in your properties file and retrieve that value(not sure if this is what you want). See below.

config.properties

```
my.xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config><Name>Goku</Name></Config>
```

ReadXml.java:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadXml{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("my.xml"));
    }
}
```